# which generated class is using for string type primary key in hibernate java? or any need of generator class for string type

Tags: java, hibernate

Which generated class is using for String type Primary key in Hibernate Java? or   any need of Generator Class for String type?

an error came when I am using update

> org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

This is my Entity class Book.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
//import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
@Entity
@Table(name="book1")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true,length=20)
    private String ACC_NO;
    private String CALL_NO;
    private String AUTHOR;
    private String TITLE;
    private String IMPRINT;
    private String YEAR;
    private String EDITION;
    private String SUBJECT;
    private String SERIES;
    private String PAGES;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
    private Date DATE_RELEASE;
    private String BOOK_STATUS;
    private Byte RESER_STATUS;
    public String getACC_NO() {
        return ACC_NO;
    }
    public void setACC_NO(String aCC_NO) {
        ACC_NO = aCC_NO;
    }
    public String getCALL_NO() {
        return CALL_NO;
    }
    public void setCALL_NO(String cALL_NO) {
        CALL_NO = cALL_NO;
    }
    public String getAUTHOR() {
        return AUTHOR;
    }
    public void setAUTHOR(String aUTHOR) {
        AUTHOR = aUTHOR;
    }
    public String getTITLE() {
        return TITLE;
    }
    public void setTITLE(String tITLE) {
        TITLE = tITLE;
    }
    public String getIMPRINT() {
        return IMPRINT;
    }
    public void setIMPRINT(String iMPRINT) {
        IMPRINT = iMPRINT;
    }
    public String getYEAR() {
        return YEAR;
    }
    public void setYEAR(String yEAR) {
        YEAR = yEAR;
    }
    public String getEDITION() {
        return EDITION;
    }
    public void setEDITION(String eDITION) {
        EDITION = eDITION;
    }
    public String getSUBJECT() {
        return SUBJECT;
    }
    public void setSUBJECT(String sUBJECT) {
        SUBJECT = sUBJECT;
    }
    public String getSERIES() {
        return SERIES;
    }
    public void setSERIES(String sERIES) {
        SERIES = sERIES;
    }
    public String getPAGES() {
        return PAGES;
    }
    public void setPAGES(String pAGES) {
        PAGES = pAGES;
    }
    public String getBOOK_STATUS() {
        return BOOK_STATUS;
    }
    public void setBOOK_STATUS(String bOOK_STATUS) {
        BOOK_STATUS = bOOK_STATUS;
    }
    public Byte getRESER_STATUS() {
        return RESER_STATUS;
    }
    public void setRESER_STATUS(Byte rESER_STATUS) {
        RESER_STATUS = rESER_STATUS;
    }
    public Date getDATE_RELEASE() {
        return DATE_RELEASE;
    }
    public void setDATE_RELEASE(Date dATE_RELEASE) {
        DATE_RELEASE = dATE_RELEASE;
    }
}


**Update command in BookDAOImpl.java is below use for both save and Update**

@Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveBook(Book Book) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(Book);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the entity class and code use to update?

Comment: I don´t know if that's the problem but you got a typo in your saveBook method - (Book Book) should be (Book book) and you should save your book with lowercase in the sessionFactory.

Comment: Also your class members' naming is not quite java-compliant. You should not use uppercases to name variable members. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Thank you for the advise. i just chaged. my question is whether we need a  generator class for a string primary key

Answer (score 1):

For String-based primary keys, you have two options:

- Use one of the UUID generators to store a generated UUID as  a String.
- Write your own String-based custom generator.

The other generators in Hibernate primarily deal with numeric values that are either obtained from a table specific `IDENTITY` or `AUTO_INCREMENT` based column or a `SEQUENCE` supplied either by the database's sequence support or the custom `hibernate_sequences` table.